# Password entropy requirements for online dictionary attacks on OPAQUE?

Tags: passwords, entropy, pake, dictionary-attack

My understanding is that for PAKE protocols such as OPAQUE (https://eprint.iacr.org/2018/163.pdf), the the adversary has no choice but to just do online attacks on the password. If this is true, I have 2 questions (which hopefully can be answered with references to RFC, NIST, etc.):

1. What is a reasonable entropy level of the password so that is it practically immune to online dictionary attacks?
2. What are good password requirements to enforce this minimum entropy level?

Thanks!

Comment: It would be difficult to give an answer to this without asking "how many on-line queries can an attacker perform?"  The answer to this depends on the application (how much rate limitation do they do on a failed login request?)

Comment: I agree. I don't know typical parameter for this. Is it possible to give a somewhat generic answer? E.g. with N on-line guesses rate limit?